# PHP - adding new element in array using for loop?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

*please don't angry cause I knew it's duplicated questions!*

I need to add the new element to the array using for loop, cause I need increment some values to bring new indexes.

```
$array = [['first'=>'a', 'second'=>'b', 'third'=>'c'], ['first'=>'d', 'second'=>'e', 'third'=>'f'],['first'=>'g', 'second'=>'h', 'third'=>'i'] ];

$length = count($array);

for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++){
    array_push($array, ["number"=>$i]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

and var_dump show:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'first' => string 'a' (length=1)
      'second' => string 'b' (length=1)
      'third' => string 'c' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'first' => string 'd' (length=1)
      'second' => string 'e' (length=1)
      'third' => string 'f' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'first' => string 'g' (length=1)
      'second' => string 'h' (length=1)
      'third' => string 'i' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'number' => int 1
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'number' => int 2
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'number' => int 3
```

`array(size=6)`, and I need just `array(size=3)`.
I need `'number' => int 1`, `'number' => int 2`, `'number' => int 3` inside the existing `$array`

***Thank You!***

Comment: YOu mean 3 sized array with 3 indexes that is 1, 2, 3 right?

Comment: yes please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this :

```
$array = [['first'=>'a', 'second'=>'b', 'third'=>'c'], ['first'=>'d', 'second'=>'e', 'third'=>'f'],['first'=>'g', 'second'=>'h', 'third'=>'i'] ];

$length = count($array);

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $array[$k]['number']=$k+1;  
}

var_dump($array);
```

the output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["second"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["third"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["second"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["third"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["number"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["second"]=>
    string(1) "h"
    ["third"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["number"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Comment: you are welcome.Can you please mark your issue as solved...?@ruli